# My Android device cannot retrieve the internal credential

Tags: javascript, android, webauthn

After I succeeded to make 'platform' credential, I tried to retrieve the credential to get the assertion.

but when I passed the `credentialRequestOptions` as below

```js
const publicKeyCredentialRequestOptions = {
        challenge: Uint8Array.from(challengeFromServer, (c) => c.charCodeAt(0)),
        allowCredentials: [
            {
              transports: ["internal"],
              type: "public-key",
              id: Uint8Array.from(credentialId, (c) => c.charCodeAt(0))
            }
        ],
        timeout: 60000,
        userVerification: "required",
        rpId: rpId
}
```

the userVerification pop-up, finger-print verification, appeared as normal

but after I fulfilled it, I got **"The operation either timed out or was not allowed"** exception.

when I remove the **tansports: ["internal"]** option in allowCredential, my device asked me "choose the secure key from BlueTooth, NFC or USB"

it seems my device does not support 'internal' credential.

Testing Env

- Device : SM-N971N(Galaxy Note10)
- OS : Android12
- Browser : Chrome 107.0.5304.91

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that the credential ID is incorrect. Try logging it with console.log() immediately after registration, and immediately before making the assertion to ensure that there's no an encoding issue.